# MQTT cluster information

Tags: mqtt

I am quite confused about MQTT clustering, it doesn't seem to be part of the MQTT protocol and I was wondering if each MQTT broker implementation has its own way to implement it. Also, do you know which kind of information are shared between cluster nodes? It seems like it retains information related to the session related to pub/sub but not the messages, is that correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing in the MQTT protocol about clustering brokers. There is support for bridging topics between 2 brokers, but this is purely at the message level, it carries no information about clients or sessions.

Any clustering is implemented independently by a given broker, what information shared would also be dependent on the that implementation. But would need to include the following:

- Client Session information, including subscriptions
- Message
- Information about which messages have been delivered to what clients